# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Sinn" und "Zweck"?

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern "Sinn" und "Zweck"? Manchmal sagt man ja "Der Sinn und Zweck ist, ...".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Die Wörter *Sinn* und *Zweck* haben eine ähnliche Bedeutung.

**Sinn**: *Bedeutung* von etwas

> Dein Satz ergibt keinen Sinn.

**Zweck**: *Ziel* von etwas, *Absicht* hinter etwas

> Der Zweck von StackExchange ist, gute Antworten auf Fragen zu finden.

Am besten erkennt man den Unterschied, wenn man die jeweils gegenteiligen Begriffe (als Adjektive) miteinander vergleicht:

- unsinnig
- zwecklos

Sie können aber unter Umständen auch ungefähr dasselbe aussagen:

> Der Sinn dieser Änderung ist mir nicht klar.
>
> Der Zweck dieser Änderung ist mir nicht klar.

---

Der Ausdruck *Sinn und Zweck* ist auch eine Redensart, die wohl aus *ohne Sinn und Zweck* abgeleitet ist.

Die Wörter *Sinn* und *Zweck* haben also in Bezug auf Sinn und Zweck viele Ähnlichkeiten. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Etwas kann durchaus sinnlos sein, aber einen bestimmten Zweck verfolgen.
Ein schönes Beispiel ist ein Flashmob:
Es wird eine total sinnlose Aktion durchgeführt, deren einziger Zweck es ist, Aufmerksamkeit zu erregen.

Ich spiele auf den Unterschied an, dass die Aktion in diesem Fall zwar ein bestimmtes Ziel verfolgt, aber es keine Rolle spielt, was für eine Aktion zu diesem Ziel führt.

Comment: Ich dachte immer, "Sinn" würde "Semantik" bedeuten. Also z.B., der "Sinn" der Ziffernfolge "123" ist eine Zahl. Ist dem nicht so? Wie erklärt sich das Wort "Sinn" in Bezug auf eine Flashmob-Veranstaltung? Wird her der gleiche Bezug hergestellt wie bei "Sinn des Lebens"? Ich da verstehe ich nicht so ganz, wo die genaue Bedeutung von "Sinn" liegt. Wo ist der Unterschied zu "Zweck des Lebens"?

Comment: Den Bezug zur Semantik finde ich gut, der Sinn einer Ziffernfolge ist die Zahl, der Zweck einer Ziffernfolge wäre dann z.B. die (im Vergleich zur Ausschreibung in Worten) kurze Darstellung dieser Zahl. Ich persönlich verwende "Sinn" und "Zweck" analog, je nach Kontext. Beim Flashmob wäre der Sinn dann die konkrete Aktion, der Zweck das "auf sich aufmerksam machen". Zum sinn des Lebens müsste ich erst ein wenig sinnieren, aber ich befürchte, diese Frage ist so tiefgründig, das hat bei mir keinen Zweck (und mir fehlt dazu leider momentan die Zeit).

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, dass mit dem Sinn der moralische, ethische oder soziale Nutzen einer Handlung gemeint ist, der auch in materiellen Gewinnen gemessen werden kann. Wohingegen der Zweck einer Sache darin besteht, ein bestimmtes Ziel zu erreichen. Im Englischen haben wir es tatsächlich geschafft, dies in ein Wort zu fassen: "objective" (nicht zu verwechseln mit der traditionell falschen Übersetzung zu Ziel,  = aim, goal, target!). "The objective" ist das hergestellte Ergebnis einer Handlung oder Nichthandlung. Ein Beispiel: Das "objective" der Beschäftigung einer Putzfrau ist die Einhaltung der deutschen Hygienevorschriften und das Wohlbefinden der Mitarbeiterin. Der Sinn; ein glücklicher Mitarbeiter ist ein guter Mitarbeiter, und die zweckgebundenen Geldstrafen werden dem Unternehmen nicht für schlechte Gesundheits- und Sicherheitsstandards verhängt.
Excuse my German, I am Scottish!

Comment: Das ist sehr gutes Deutsch und in meinen Augen auch eine sehr gute Antwort. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sinn ist tendenziell feierlicher und wird in philosophischen Debatten eher thematisiert als der Zweck. Man fragt eher nach dem Sinn des Lebens als nach dem Zweck. Aber ich stimme splattne zu, dass es keine scharfe Trennung gibt.

Comment: Zweck ist eine glasklare Kategorie (Aristoteles, Kant, ...). Sinn ist etwas, das Sinneswahrnehmungen ermöglicht. Insofern halte ich deine Unterscheidung (insbesondere mit Bezug auf philosophische Debatten) für zweifelhaft.

Comment: @Olafant: Philosophische Debatten sind auch, aber nicht alleiniger Scope der Wörter Sinn und Zweck. Die meisten Verwender der Wörter haben wahrscheinlich nie eine Zeile von Aristoteles oder Kant gelesen. Bei Aristoteles, der sich ja nicht der dt. Sprache bemächtigt hat, käme noch die Frage ins Spiel, wie glasklar etwaige Übersetzungen sind. Profis auf dem Gebiet der Philosophie gefallen sich meist, solchhe Schlüsselbegriffe in der Originalschreibung zu verwenden, weil sie nicht 1:1 in unsere heutige Sprache passen.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Erklärung resultiert aus der deutschen Teilung.

> Die innerdeutsche Grenzanlage mit Selbstschusseinrichtungen markierte den Zweck. Dieser bestand darin, jeglichen Grenzübertritt zu verhindern. Nach dem 9.November 1989 erfüllte die Grenzanlage immer noch ihren Zweck, doch weil sie ihren Sinn verloren hatte, war der Zweck auch überflüssig geworden.
> Gott sei dank!

Danken möchte ich auch dem Urheber des [schottischen Beitrages](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62847/36196). Dessen qualifizierte Erklärung zu „objective“ und die Unterscheidung zu „goal“ und „target“ war mir sehr hilfreich.

Comment: Ohne Link zu dem schottischen Beitrag ist der letzte Absatz für kaum einen Leser hilfreich. Ob der Autor von dort hier mitliest und in den Genuss des Danks kommt, halte ich auch für fraglich.