# „Sinn und Zweck“ anstelle von „Zweck“ zu schreiben, ist das ein Stilmittel?

Tags: style, rhetoric

Dass *Sinn* und *Zweck* teils [weitgehend übereinstimmen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/880/5437), teils stark [abweichen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1007/5437) können, wird zur Frage 
[Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Sinn" und "Zweck"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/878/5437) eingehend behandelt.

In [einer der Antworten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4002/5437) zu [Singular/Plural bei Aufzählungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4000/5437) finde ich erklärt, dass man das Stilmittel der *Alliteration* verwendet, um die Aufmerksamkeit zu verstärken.

Wenn ich aber z.B. anstelle von

> Zweck der Übung ist ...

sage

> Sinn und Zweck der Übung ist ...

scheint mir die Absicht dieselbe wie bei der Alliteration (aus meiner Sicht verstärkt durch die Wahl der Singularform „ist“). Nur liegen hier keine Übereinstimmungen von Wortteilen vor, sondern solche inhaltlicher Art. Der Versuch, mich [bei Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorisches_Stilmittel) zu informieren, hat mich ziemlich entmutigt, und die Frage per Websuche zu klären, halte ich für aussichtslos, weil *zu meta*.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn ich bei Wikipedia recherchiere, stoße ich auf die [Tautologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautologie_(Sprache)) und das [Hendiadyoin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadyoin):

> „Tautologie“ kann zum einen bedeuten, dass dasselbe (dieselbe Sache, derselbe Sachverhalt) mit einem sinngleichen oder sinnverwandten Ausdruck noch einmal gesagt wird.
>
> Beispiele: „bereits schon“, „still und leise“, „voll und ganz“, „nie und nimmer“, „[…] diente so auf diese Weise einer Ameise als Speise“.
>
> Tautologie in diesem Sinne einer „Wiedergabe des gleichen Sachverhalts durch mehrere Synonyme“ dürfte dabei der Regelfall sein.

Die [Liste rhetorischer Stilmittel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_rhetorischer_Stilmittel) bei Wikipedia gibt als weitere Beispiele noch an:

> hegen und pflegen“; „immer und ewig“; „angst und bange“; „Not und Elend“; „List und Tücke“

Was sich aber überschneidet mit dem Artikel zum [Hendiadyoin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadyoin):

> Das Hendiadyoin ist im Regelfall ein feststehender Ausdruck (Phraseologismus), also eine Paar- oder Zwillingsformel. Hendiadyoin-Konstruktionen können nach unterschiedlichen Mustern gebildet sein:
>
> - als phraseologische Verbindung zweier annähernd gleichbedeutender Begriffe (wie bei „Grund und Boden“, „nie und nimmer“)
> - als phraseologische Verbindung zweier ähnlicher Begriffe, die gemeinsam einen (neugebildeten) Begriff bezeichnen (beispielsweise „Feuer und Flamme“ = begeistert)
> - als beiordnende Verbindung zweier Substantive, die zusammen einen einzigen Gegenstand bezeichnen (wie „Haus und Hof“ = das ganze Anwesen).

Mit einer langen Liste weiterer Beispiele, u.a.

> - Bausch und Bogen
> - Dach und Fach
> - Lug und Trug

Die Abgrenzung der beiden Begriffe scheint nicht ganz einfach zu sein.

Comment: Aha, so wird mir die Sache schon klarer, ich kannte [Tautologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautologie_(Logik) "Tautologie_(Logik)") nur im Dunstkreis der Logik. Und der Anfang der Wikipedia-Seite las sich nicht so vielversprechend. Jetzt aber habe ich ihn durchgelesen und am Ende einen interessanten Verweis entdeckt, der es wahrscheinlich besser trifft: [**Perissologie**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perissologie)

Comment: Ah, das hatte ich übersehen. Stimmt, das passt noch deutlich besser :)